# SQL Server Pivot/Unpivot an entire table (100+ fields)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with this project the way it is.  What I need to do is take a table with about 100 fields and compare two records, determining which fields don't match.

The best way I could think of was to pivot them, so this:

```
KeyID    Field1    Field2   Field3    Field4   Field5    Field6
42       Apples    Pears    Blue      Hills    Dog       iPhone
65       Apples    Plums    Red       Hills    Cat       iPhone
```

becomes this:

```
FieldName    KeyID_42    KeyID_65
Field1       Apples      Apples
Field2       Pears       Plums
Field3       Blue        Red
Field4       Hills       Hills
Field5       Dog         Cat
Field6       iPhone      iPhone
```

And then I can run a query against that like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyPivot
WHERE KeyID_42 <> KeyID_65
```

and I should be left with this:

```
FieldName    KeyID_42    KeyID_65
Field2       Pears       Plums
Field3       Blue        Red
Field5       Dog         Cat
```

However, with a table with 100 or so fields, listing every single one of them in a PIVOT statement isn't gonna be pretty.  And I may have to do this with another table later.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?  One that doesn't require listing each field separately?

## EDIT:

I'm at this point, but getting many errors like this: `Invalid column name 'UpdateTime'.`

The code I'm using is this:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblSQLAdminInventory')
           --AND C.Name <> 'EffectiveDate' 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select KeyID, ID1, ID2
     from tblSQLAdminInventory
     unpivot
     (
        KeyID
        for ID1 in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u
     unpivot
     (
        KeyID
        for ID2 in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u     
     '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Without listing all fields, you'll need to use `dynamic sql` to `unpivot` your results.  Several examples on SO for doing this.

Comment: Double unpivot will not do the trick. Why do the unpivot twice?

Comment: Will the where clause always be WHERE KeyID_42 <> KeyID_65 or this needs to be dynamic as well?

Comment: TT - I'm struggling with Unpivot.  I probably have the syntax wrong.  Kamran - The keys will change, the user will decide which two numbers to compare so that needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Note that your table is limited to 4096 records because SELECT queries are [explicitly limited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) to 4096 columns.  My instincts still say that this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @BaconBits - The output should only be 3 fields, and not more than "around 100" records.  Assume my sample data goes out to somewhere around Field100.  If Pivot/Unpivot isn't the best solution (and it might not be), can you suggest another way of comparing 2 records and reporting which fields from those records are out of sync?

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot only once, and then write as follows:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    -- the query with unpivot but only once 
    -- UNPIVOT(value FOR ID IN (...))
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte AS c1
    INNER JOIN cte AS c2 ON
        c2.ID=c1.ID
WHERE
    c1.KeyId=42 AND
    c2.KeyId=65 AND
    c1.value<>c2.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, as it is dynamic you do not need to worry about the number of the fields:

Assumption: The column names will always be in the format Field

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE temp2 (KeyID INT, Field1 VARCHAR(20), Field2 VARCHAR(20), Field3 VARCHAR(20), Field4 VARCHAR(20), Field5 VARCHAR(20), Field6 VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO temp2
VALUES
       (42, 'Apples', 'Pears', 'Blue', 'Hills', 'Dog', 'iPhone'),
       (65, 'Apples', 'Plums', 'Red', 'Hills', 'Cat', 'iPhone');
```

Query:

```
-- Where clause params
DECLARE @whereClauseParam VARCHAR(MAX) = '[42] <> [65]' --<-- User will need to determine what the condition will be

--Get the Fields required for the initial pivot
DECLARE @Fields VARCHAR(MAX)= '';

SELECT @Fields+=QUOTENAME(t.name)+', '
FROM sys.columns AS t
WHERE t.object_id = OBJECT_ID('temp2')
      AND t.name LIKE 'Field[0-9]%';

-- Get the KeyId's with alias added
DECLARE @keyIDs VARCHAR(MAX)= '';

SELECT @keyIDs+=QUOTENAME(t.KeyID)+' AS [KeyID_'+CAST(t.KeyID AS VARCHAR(10))+'], '
FROM temp2 AS t;

-- Get the KeyId's without alias
DECLARE @keyIDs1 VARCHAR(MAX)= '';

SELECT @keyIDs1+=QUOTENAME(t.KeyID)+', '
FROM temp2 AS t;

--Generate Dynamic SQL
DECLARE @SQL2 VARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT  Value AS FieldName,';

SELECT @SQL2+=SUBSTRING(@keyIDs, 1, LEN(@keyIDs)-1)+'
FROM
(SELECT KeyID , Value , FieldName
FROM 
   (SELECT KeyID,'+SUBSTRING(@Fields, 1, LEN(@Fields)-1)+'
   FROM temp2) p --<-- you will need to change the name to point to your table
UNPIVOT
   (FieldName  FOR value IN 
      ('+SUBSTRING(@Fields, 1, LEN(@Fields)-1)+')
)AS unpvt) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(FieldName)
FOR KeyID IN ('+SUBSTRING(@keyIDs1, 1, LEN(@keyIDs1)-1)+')
) AS PivotTable
WHERE '+@whereClauseParam

PRINT(@SQL2);
EXECUTE(@SQL2);
```

Result:

[image]

In response to the comment "This returns error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function :)":

[image]

Comment: Kamran joon, This returns error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function :)

Comment: @FLICKER did you make sure you copied the code correctly. I just ran it and it ran fine!

Comment: There is a value (lower case v). it should be Value (upper case V). I was getting erro because of my collation. Now, it works. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, in a much larger environment this becomes less usable.  It's been running over 30 minutes on my table with no results yet.